# Html editor that allows viewing and editing html code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, editor

I have a site that I need to be able to edit html both through an html editor and an output viewer. Basically I need to have two windows. One for seeing the html itself so it can be edited and then another for the output for the html. I also need both windows to stay up to date with each other. So a user should be able to go into the output window and change things there and the html will reflect those changes and vice versa. Is there an API that accomplishes this well? I have not been able to find much. I'm not set on a language but I am assuming that for a live update between the windows angularjs is the way to go.

Comment: have you tried a search for 'WYSIWYG HTML editor online'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use tinymce; you'd only have the one window, but it's a WYSIWYG editor that will keep the look and style when saved (works basically like Microsoft Word, and puts in the header, paragraph, link, etc. tags automatically as you write).

Answer (score 0):

look at this module

https://github.com/stevermeister/ngWig

"source-mode-allowed" enable to edit content with html or to write content like you do with office

```
<ng-wig ng-model="text1" source-mode-allowed></ng-wig>
```

Exemple her 
https://plnkr.co/edit/JVOI2l2gnZMKORMWjAEZ?p=preview